# No screen while power cord out Asus R556L

Tags: windows, laptop, power-supply, hdmi

1. When connecto via power cord everything is fine. I can switch between laptop screen and tv and computer boots from laptop screen with no problem.
2. When diconnecting the power cord - WITH ONLY BATTERY, screen get almost blank - in a very hard ligh you can see shades of image.
3. There is no way using the laptop screen - but HDMI connection to tv works fine, even WITHOUT power-chord connected!
4. I changed the power blanace via windows, but nothing helps, and since the screen doesn't even show picture at boot - I don't think it's a windows problem. Battery is 100%. I'm using WINDOWS 10.

Not helping soultions:
Brightness Increasing
Changing Power plan

I opened the case and re-connected battery but nothing changed.
Also when booting with battery no image - even before WINDOWS loading.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what's wrong with this question and how it should be improved.

Comment: How old is the battery?

Comment: L565A isn't a known laptop model afaik...so this is almost impossible to help. Please post your exact specs and model. Pictures of the labels if you're not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Check brightness controls in the bios and graphics card options or reset bios to defaults. Take note of secure boot and hard drive ahci, legacy, raid options before you reset as it can cause boot problems when changed.